# Deleting Sheet from workbook - python

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to delete a sheet from my Excel file and i am trying this code:

```py
import openpyxl

workbook1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_file_folder + input_file_name)
print(workbook1.sheetnames)
Sheet1 = workbook1['Sheet1']
workbook1.remove(Sheet1)
workbook1.save(input_file_folder + input_file_name)
writer.save()
```

The sheet names are printing out to be:
`['Sheet1', 'Candidate Campaign 0', 'Candidate Campaign 6', 'Candidate Campaign 7', 'Candidate Campaign 8', 'Valid Campaigns']`

But somehow the "Sheet1' is not getting deleted anyhow.

I even tried:

```py
n = workbook1.sheetnames
workbook1.remove(n[1])
```

but this doesnt work as well.

Can anyone please pinpoint what's wrong. As this command is working with other sheets but only `Sheet1`(the default one) is not getting deleted.

Comment: `del workbook1['Sheet1']`

Comment: Hi @CharlieClark- it worked. Thanks. If you can post it as an answer, i can accept it :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```py
del workbook1['Sheet1']
```

As suggested by @Charlie Clark

Answer (score 21):

Save the file using `workbook1.save()` instead of `writer.save()`.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(file_workbook)
if 'Sheet1' in wb.sheetnames:
    wb.remove(wb['Sheet1'])
wb.save(file_workbook)
```

Comment: Saving the file using workbook.save made a huge difference -- no more damaged files. Thanks for the note, @SparkAndShine.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because `del workbook['Sheet1']` is now deprecated [as described in the docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=workbook#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.remove)

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods you can delete sheet from workbook. `remove_sheet`, `remove` and `del`. However, `remove_sheet` is deprecated.

```
wb.remove_sheet(wb['Sheet'])

wb.remove(wb['Sheet'])

del wb['Sheet']
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).