# Delete last sheet of excel using python - ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
file_workbook = 'archivo.xlsx'
file_workbook2 = 'sample (TD).xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(file_workbook)
if 'BASE' in wb.sheetnames:
    wb.remove(wb['BASE'])
wb.save(file_workbook2)
```

**ERROR**

> Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed warn(msg)
> UserWarning: Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and
> will be removed warn(msg)
> UserWarning: Slicer List extension is not supported and will be
> removed warn(msg)

[imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfLCM.png)

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Make sure your code is correctly formatted, and has the same indentation as what you are actually trying to use. Make sure to show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, with the same fixed-font formatting. Make sure to *explain an actual problem*, in complete English sentences. These only look like warnings; does the code give the right result? But most importantly, make sure to **ask a question**.

Comment: You can also try `del wb['BASE']`. See related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58585857/deleting-sheet-from-workbook-python).

Comment: These are just warning messages. Your code did remove the sheet 'BASE' right?

Comment: The warning is **not** an error and has nothing to do with deleting the worksheet.

Comment: @CodeMonkey, i had already try that, didnt work

Comment: @moken,@CharlieClark didnt remove sheet BASE

Comment: As mentioned these messages are not about deleting the sheet, your code will delete that sheet if it exists. Sorry but have check; is the sheet name definitely called 'BASE', all uppercase since if its 'base' or 'Base" or other combination of upper/lower case letters it will not match the 'if' test and therefore not execute the delete statement. And are you definitely checking 'sample (TD).xlsx' and not the original 'archivo.xlsx'?

Comment: @moken, BASE exists, full UPPER CASE

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't then you need to debug your code if using an IDE with that capability or at least add some print statements to determine the delete statement is being executed.
If you cannot debug the code then the following print lines will help check the sheet is there and what happens after the delete.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
file_workbook = 'archivo.xlsx'
file_workbook2 = 'sample (TD).xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(file_workbook)
print(wb.sheetnames) # <- show sheets existing in 'archivo.xlsx'
if 'BASE' in wb.sheetnames:
    print("Executing sheet remove") # <- If statement is True
    wb.remove(wb['BASE'])
print(wb.sheetnames) # <- show sheets after deleting 'BASE' to be saved as 'sample (TD).xlsx'
wb.save(file_workbook2)
```