# delete some sheets from some excel files

Tags: python-3.x

I have 1000 Excel files, each containing 20 sheets with the same names. I want to delete some sheets from all these 1000 files. I have a relatively average knowledge of Python and I want it to be done in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use openpyxl library as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58585857/deleting-sheet-from-workbook-python) topic:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(file_workbook)
if 'Sheet_name' in wb.sheetnames:
    wb.remove(wb['Sheet_name'])
wb.save(file_workbook)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous user said, it is better to use the openpyxl library. Now you just have to open all the excel files, this is done with the glob library.

```
import openpyxl
import glob
#select all excel archives
xlsx_files = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
#read individual excel archive(workbook)
for read in xlsx_files:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(read)
    #example sheet name Prove
    if 'Prove' in wb.sheetnames:
        wb.remove(wb['Prove'])
    #Save workbook
    wb.save(read)
```